# Symfony 2.4 cron job not running

Tags: symfony, cron, symfony-2.4

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php5.6 -f /var/www/utt/app/console reservation:createPropertyStatements 15 --env=prod &>> /var/www/utt/createPropertyStatements.log
```

Symfony 2.4 cron job not running. The command runs when we run it manually eg:

```
/usr/bin/php5.6 -f /var/www/utt/app/console reservation:createPropertyStatements 15 --env=prod &>> /var/www/utt/createPropertyStatements.log
```

That works

I have also created a sample bash script that runs from the cron tab  - */5 * * * *  root /bin/bash /var/www/utt/timer.sh

and that runs as well.

we are logged into server via ssh as root and are accessing the crontab via - nano /etc/crontab

Comment: `crontab -l` shows the right crontab ? Did you try to run command manually in `prod` mode?

Comment: Yes and yes env=prod

Comment: `cd` into the project directory before running console. `cd /var/www/uttt/app && /usr/bin/php5.6 console reservation:createPropertyStatements 15 --env=prod`.